# How to call a variable inside a function - discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, coroutine

```
@bot.command()
async def blackjack(ctx):
    cards = "♣️3"
   
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(msg):
        globals cards
        print(cards)
```

I'm making a blackjack command in discord.py but ran into a problem where the variable "cards" is not defined (because it isn't a local variable)
I'm not sure how to fix this. I tried including "globals cards" but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't access the variable because you define it in a separate method. If you define the variable outside of both methods, then all of your methods may access and change the variable freely.

**Code**

```py
cards = "♣️3"

@bot.command()
async def blackjack(ctx):
    #code here
    pass

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    print(cards)
```

Comment: That is correct, but you should be aware that global variables like this are not reccomended. If you're trying to store global states, it is reccomended to use some kind of dedicated database.